# Revealing details about other people

Tags: discussion, support, ethics

In [my answer to "How to write a white paper for a non-academic"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/14659). I mentioned that I know a true story, an example of such a situation with a "happy end". Now, it was requested that I relieve more information about this, which I originally didn't want to.

**What do I know:** I know who are the authors, I know one of them in person (from a conference) and he made a conference talk from where I know the information. I know quite well the topic of the papers.

**My question:** Is it non-ethical to publish this information here?

**My view of pros:** it's all positive, therefore it's not really speaking behind their back.

**My view of cons:** I don't want to be a paparazzi that publishes such information on a random webpage/blog/... without the people's consent.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think anyone *requested* details… but people are curious, especially went it sounds like a good story! So they *ask* for details.

Don't feel pressured to reveal anything, if it's not public knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I would venture to add that, specifically, if we are considering anecdotes, if said anecdote is public information, then I don't think that it is a breach of privacy to reveal their names and other details (affiliations, gender etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If their story is published, you would have to cite them as the authors… in that case, revealing their names and credentials would be fair ground. If the information you have is privileged meaning you have access to the info because you are friends, you happen to know them personally or they asked you to proof read some papers. It would not be ok to use such info especially on a public site.
If you are truly concerned, go on and ask for their blessing/permission.